# Javascript called by blazor code happens when DOM not yet ready?

Tags: javascript, webassembly, blazor

I've a javascript function that has to create graph:

```
<script>
    window.setGraph = (lab, ser) => {
        console.log(document.getElementById("weather-chart"));
        console.log(lab);
        console.log(ser);
        var chart = new Chartist.Line('#weather-chart', {
            labels: lab,
            series: ser
        });

        console.log("done");
        return true;
    }    
</script>
```

This function is called by one of my blazor component:

```
protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
{
    some-data-a = await RetrieveSomeData();
    some-data-b = await RetrieveSomeOtherData();
    JSRuntime.Current.InvokeAsync<bool>("setGraph", some-data-a, some-data-b);
}
```

Everything is executed, my `console.log` are called. But it appears that at this moment my element `#weather-chart` cannot be found, because I get this:

```
chartist.min.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null
    at Object.c.createSvg (chartist.min.js:8)
    at f.d [as createChart] (chartist.min.js:8)
    at f.h (chartist.min.js:8)
```

**AND**
 my console.log(document....) is returning null.

If I go to this page, I've the error, and if just after getting this error I do something like `window.setGraph([1,2,3], [[1,2,3]])` in my chrome developer tools, everything is initialized correctly.

So what did I do wrong? Why chartist doesn't seems to be able to find the element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript that executes after page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load)

Comment: You seem to be trying to execute your code before all the elements have been loaded run your script after the page has loaded all the elements

Comment: @AndréDion nothing to do with that. It's called by blazor, so its way after the page has been loaded

Comment: @casualcoder I think it's the only callback that Blazor offer, no?

Comment: @J4N what does your console.log prints? are the values correct?

Comment: @J4N Well Blazor itself says its an "unsupported experimental web framework" can you make timestamps for when your page loads and when the callback is executed to ensure that it indeed happens after your page has loaded. (as all evidence points to your code working fine just trying to access elements which don't exist yet)

Comment: It's pretty obvious that the element with id `weather-chart` doesn't exist at the time the `setGraph` function is called, or at all for that matter; you haven't actually showed that part of the solution.

Comment: You should send an elementRef reference for #weather-chart to your JS function, and you shouldn't do: document.getElementById("weather-chart")

Answer (score -1):

It appears that blazor's databinding was taking some time to display the html. So basically after I set the _items, it was changing the template, but not fast enough for the line after this(not sure why, since there was an await).

Comment: keep in mind it IS experimental, if you can make a verifiable example with the await you could file a bug on their site to have them figure out the unexpected behavior

Comment: I just think that the refresh of the view is invoked.